# How to retrive data from a table depending on two matched values from different tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have `emp` table in which `empId` is the primary key and another table `empLogin` in which the `empId` is a foreign key, whenever the user login the system its ID is inserted from `emp` table into `empLogin` table this `empId` is very important in billing and reciepting forms and I want to show the employee name instead of its ID ...

I've written these codes for this idea but it gives me an exception which is

> The multi-part identifier "empLogin.empId" could not be bound

My codes are:

```
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select empName from emp where emp.empId=empLogin.empId", cn);
dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
dr2.Read();
rcptEmpNametxt.Text = dr["empName"].ToString();
dr.Close();
```

Comment: You need to join tables.

Comment: Your question is unclear and, I think,  leading to misleading answers. At the point your code is run, do you have the emp id or the emplogin id? Or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing JOIN between `emp` AND `empLogin`

```
select empName 
from emp 
INNER JOIN empLogin ON emp.empId=empLogin.empId
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is:

```
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select empName from emp, empLogin where emp.empId=empLogin.empId", cn);
```

but this one will be more useful:

```
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select empName from emp inner join empLogin on emp.empId=empLogin.empId", cn);
```

Comment: This might work if the current user is always the first in the result set.

Comment: @MegaTron Yes sir the current user is always the first in the result set, and I'm thank full for your help , this worked with me and I'll keep this in my mind for future ... regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables and do that, there is no join used in your inline sql statement, that's the reasons it throwing "The multi-part identifier "empLogin.empId" could not be bound" error.

Comment: Yes sir and I'll keep this in my mind for future ... rgards

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work ...

```
SELECT TOP 1 empName
FROM EMP E
INNER JOIN EMPLOGIN EL ON E.empId = EL.empId 
ORDER BY ... DESC
```

The `...` should be replaced with the `primary key` of table `EMPLOGIN`.
I hope this helps : )